# Analyze an image displayed on screen in java

Tags: java, image-processing

Say my wallpaper is full of circles, and i want to find the coordinates of all red circles.
is there a java class that can help me out..?

Comment: You might want to break the problem down a bit. It's very unlikely that there would be a single class that would do everything you need. You first need to get hold of the image and then perform the analysis you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get the color of specific pixel.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
int c = image.getRGB(x,y);
int  red = (c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int  green = (c & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int  blue = c & 0x000000ff;
// and the Java Color is ...
Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
```

(the code snippet is taken from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0257.html)). 
Once you can do this you can go over all pixels of your image, find the red once and then try to find circles.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This should help!